# How to hold a json inside a json, with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I need to do a API response like this one https://devdactic.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com/tutorial/db.json
With Spring Boot and Java17,
this data in local DataBase...

Comment: Try a nested class structure then you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired Json, You can create your pojo's like this

```
    public class object{
    private String database;
    private Integer version;
    private boolean encrypted;
    private String mode;
    private List<Table> tables;}

public class Table{
    private String name;
    private List<Schema> schema;
    private List<Value> values;}
```

you should get the idea now, same way you can create Schema and Value Objects.